# Line and rectangle intersection

Tags: python, polygon, graph-algorithm, intersection, line-intersection

I have a rectangle and a line segment inside the rectangle, and the line can be extended on both sides. I know the coordinates of the rectangle's four vertices as well as the line's two vertices.

I try to write a function that would return the coordinates of the two intersection points of the line segment and the rectangle. The language I am using is python. The problem is that I am not sure which side of the rectangle the line would intersect with. So it makes my function to be extremely complex, and I am not sure if I've covered all the cases or not.

Is there an algorithm for me to do this?

Comment: Is the rectangle axis-aligned?

Comment: solve it with all four and check the allowed intervals

Comment: Yes, the rectangle is axis-aligned

Comment: Do you mean to compute the "possible intersection pts" first for each line, and then check if they are in the legal interval?

Comment: Write a routine that finds the intersection, if any, of a line segment with a line that contains another segment. Call that routine four times. This reduces the complexity of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your rectangle can be characterized as `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, and `ymax`. Find the equation of your line (see [this](http://www.mesacc.edu/~scotz47781/mat150/notes/eqn_line/Equation_Line_Two_Points_Notes.pdf)). Then solve your line for each of `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, and `ymax`.
Eliminate solutions that have `x < xmin` or `x > xmax` or `y < ymin` or `y > ymax`.